# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller, laravel-routing

I am new at Laravel. I am making a signup form in Laravel. When I use `Route::post()` and make this function in my controller, it gave me the error.

```
    <form action="{{route('userregister')}}" method="post">
```

and

```
    Route::post('/userregister',[Logincontroller::class,'userregister']);
```

Here is  my function userregister

```
    public function userregister(Request $request)
    {
        echo 'value posted';
    }
```

Comment: post full code, not fragments.

Comment: `route('userregister')` is how you resolve a [named route](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes) into a URL, but you haven't given your route a name. `userregister` is the controller method, not the name.

Comment: Just change your route,  add the route  `name` as `Route::post('/userregister',[Logincontroller::class,'userregister'])->name('userregister');`

Comment: I have changed my route name as you said but still showing the same error

Comment: You need to provide more info and do some debugging.  What URL does Route generate?  Have you tried using a hand coded route and see if it works, what is appurl set to in .env? do you have redirect set up for your site for www or http/s - all these things could affect your question.  You need to provide more informaiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code,

In your blade file

```
<form action="{{ route('user-register') }}" method="POST">
    {{ @csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

In your route file
Plz see documentation for route because of laravel versions uses defferent syntax

```
Route::post('/userregister',[Logincontroller::class,'userregister'])->name('user-register);
```

In your controller file

```
public function userregister(Request $request)
{
    var_dump($request);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this code but it doesn't work. Same error occur

Comment: Can you plz update your whole code so I will identify